# Property implementation issue

Tags: ios, synthesize

In a header file I am declaring the following objects:

```
@interface EmpresasTableViewController : UITableViewController{
    NSArray *categorias;
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSDictionary *categoriaDescription;
}
```

And in the implementation file, I synthesize the NSDictionary :

```
@synthesize categoriaDescription;
```

In another header file I am doing the same:

```
@interface DetalleEmpresaViewController : UIViewController{
    NSArray *categorias;
    NSMutableData *data;
    NSDictionary *detalleDescription;
}
```

But in the implementation file, the synthesize code line is marked as error:

```
@synthesize detalleDescription;;
```

The error is:

```
Property implementation must have its declaration in interface 'DetalleEmpresaViewController'
```

I don't understand why is it right in the first file and not in the second file...

Comment: You don't need @synthesize unless you have both setter and getter implemented in .m file

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste, or are you typing this code? Because I'm betting that in the actual code you misspelled the name in the second `@synthesize`.

Comment: @matt, I have copied the code from XCode and pasted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare property in `.h` file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *detalleDescription;
```

Comment: Look at his code. He said he did that, and proved it.

Comment: @matt: this issue is happening due to not declaring the property in .h file. If you have doubt please check it in your Xcode. I think he declared property in first class.

Comment: The error said "Property implementation must have its declaration in interface 'DetalleEmpresaViewController'" and he _did_ declare it in interface `DetalleEmpresaViewController`.

Comment: That is why I suggested that he misspelled it; this is the exact error you would get if you misspelled it in the `@synthesize` directive. But he says he didn't.

Comment: Both are right, this may be a compiler bug, in the first class I declared the property like Midhun says (sorry for not telling this before, but I was not looking at that property). The error is not well describing the issue. Thank you @matt, and sorry.

Comment: Sorry but I don't feel I've seen a satisfactory explanation of what happened here. On the evidence presented in the question, assuming the questioner did not lie, there should not be this error.

Comment: @matt, it is true, I don't lie. I was not searching for the property in the first class because the error was clear about the issue, the property must be declared in interface. After Midhun answer I detected that I had declared the property in the first class: property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *categoriaDescription; Sorry again for making you losing your time.

Comment: @matt: Yeah, I agree with your above statement. But he mentioned in his above comment that, he declared the property in first class, but forgot to mention it. Also I didn't see any spelling mismatch issue there, right now.